# Is there a more clear and efficient way to rewrite this function?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to rewrite the following function in different way but it seems that I missed something and I do not get the intended functionality?
Could anyone suggest anything?
Thanks in advance.

#### Function 1

```
function user_exists($email) {  
  $email=mysql_real_escape_string($email);
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT (`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'");
  return(mysql_result($query, 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

#### Rewritten Function 1

```
function user_exists($email) {  
  $email=mysql_real_escape_string($email);
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='$email'"); 
  $count=mysql_num_rows($query);    
  if ($query !=0) {
    return(true);   
  } else{
return(false)
}
```

Comment: Well, for starters, the second function doesn't ever return false.

Comment: Curious as to why you want to rewrite it?  What are you hoping to gain?  Also, the return statement from the original can return either true or false.  Your function only returns true in the event that the number of rows is not equal to 0.  Where as the mysql_result function checks that the first returned records first cell is equal to 1.

Comment: I think the first might be faster, but the difference is not really relevant, both are fine. I wouldn't worry about that

Comment: And you probably want to compare $count to zero, not $query.

Comment: *"it seems that I missed something"* - Please elaborate.. we can't help you unless you explain your concerns.

Comment: Mr Mike McMahon I just want to avoid the one line if statement.

Comment: Mr Mike B what I am trying to do is to check if the result of the query which can be 0 or 1  is equals to 1 and therefore true or 0 and false

Comment: @ApostolosFlessas Are you actually using Zend Framework?  If so they provide a validator that can do this for you.  See [Validators: Db_RecordExists and Db_NoRecordExists](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.Db)

Comment: this question is unrelated to Zend Framework or CakePhp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function user_exists($email) 
{  
   $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");  
   if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) 
   {
      return true; 
   }
   else
   {
      return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jamie.Unfortunately I am not allowed to give  reputation points

Answer (score 1):

```
function user_exists($email) {  
    // Escape to prevent sql injection
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
    // Query to see if the email exists in the DB
    if(false === ($query = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='$email'"))){
        // handle error
        $result = false;
    }  
    else{
        // Find a row?  Email exists, otherwise does not
        $result = (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The DB query itself could be more efficient (select a count, or at least limit to 1 result max), but this is the general idea.

Comment: @ApostolosFlessas You're welcome. If it was helpful, how about upvoting the answer?

Comment: I tried but I just created my account and I need at least 15 reputation to upvote

Answer (score 1):

```
function user_exists($email) {  
  $email=mysql_real_escape_string($email);
  $query=mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1"); 
  return mysql_num_rows($query) == 1;    
}
```

LIMIT 1 is a good practice since the engine stop searching on the first match and does not continue for the next rows

Comment: +1 because `mysql_num_rows($query) == 1` is a boolean condition already and doesn't need `? true : false`.

Comment: in this case the num of rows will be 0 and the func return false

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
function user_exists($email) 
{ 
     // Perform database query
     $email = mysql_query("SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
     if (!$email) {
          die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
     }

     // Use returned data
     while ($row = mysql_real_escape_string($email)) {
          if ($row !=0) {
               return(true);   
          }
     }
}
?>
```